# How can I move files with xargs on Linux?

Tags: linux, xargs, mv

I am trying this and it's not working:

```
ls file_* | xargs mv {} temp/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone with a multi file move version of this? (`xargs -n10` for example)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

On OS X:

```
ls file_* | xargs -J {} mv {} temp/
```

On Linux:

```
ls file_* | xargs -i {} mv {} temp/
```

Comment: whats happen with -i option

Comment: On Linux, at least, the `/` at the end is optional.  You can include it if you want, but it’s not necessary.

Comment: @Scott: I was staying as close to original, just changing to make it work.

Comment: @user1953864: `-i` (or `-J`) specify a token that will be replaced with the incoming arguments, instead of them just being tacked onto the end. `man xargs`

Comment: You _might_ need to say `-i{}`, without a space.  Or say `-I {}`.

Comment: I notice that using "%" in place of "{}" also works - what does % mean and what does {} mean? Example: ls file_* | xargs -I% mv % temp/

Comment: @dmonopoly: They don't *mean* anything. Whatever the parameter to `-i` is, it is getting replaced. `ls file_* | xargs -iFOO mv FOO temp/` works exactly the same.

Comment: `-i` is deprecated according to the manual, use `-I` (uppercase i) instead.

Answer (score 10):

Use -t "specify target directoty" at mv, it should work moving files* to destination directory /temp

ex:- #ls -l file* | xargs mv -t /temp

Answer (score 8):

`find . -name "file_*" -maxdepth 0 -exec mv {} temp/ \;`

`find` is better than `ls` where there might be more files than the number of program arguments allowed by your shell.

Comment: Note that the question suggests a desire to process only the `file_*` files in the current directory, while `find` (without additional options) will search the entire directory tree under the current directory.

Comment: Yes, true. Add `-maxdepth 0` to prevent this.

Comment: "better" is subjective. More powerful, more complex, and slower; and while `mv` doesn't care if you process files together or individually, some other uses might.

Comment: Edited (added `-maxdepth 0`)

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by @user1953864: {`-i`, `-J`} specify a token that will be replaced with the incoming arguments.

For example `ls`:

```
something.java  exampleModel.java  NewsQueryImpl.java  readme someDirectory/
```

Then to move all java files into the someDirectory folder with `xargs` would be as follows:

**On Linux**

```
ls *.java | xargs -i mv {} someDirectory/
```

**On MacOS**

```
ls *.java | xargs -J mv {} someDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be:

```
 for f in file_* ; do
   mv $f temp/$f
 done
```

The disadvantage is that it forks a new `mv` process for each file.